How does grid determine xscale and yscale values in a new R session and how should they be interpreted?
When I start an R session, the xscale and yscale values of the initial viewport are set automatically by the grid package.  I would like to understand the relationship between these values and the corresponding screen dimensions in pixels.
These are the results I get when I run the same code from RStudio with reprex:
library(grid)
convertY(unit(0, 'npc'), "native")
#> [1] 360native

Created on 2024-04-24 with reprex v2.0.2
and from the R app:
library(grid)
convertY(unit(0, 'npc'), "native")
#> [1] 504native

both immediately after starting an a new R session.
What I would like to know is :

what lead to these values being different, and
what relation do these values bear to screen dimensions


@Phil: Since my question is about the behavior of RStudio vs the R app, I was curious why you removed the rstudio tag.
